# Setting up ReactiveMongo with PlayFramework 2.2.1

Tags: playframework-2.0

I am pretty new to using PlayFramework. I signed up for MongoLab and obtained a Sandboxed version of a MongoDB. Now i came upon [ReactiveMongo](https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/Play-ReactiveMongo) plugin buts its only for Play 2.1. Is there any tutorial for setting up MongoDB with 2.3 ? I edited the build.sbt file to look like this

```
name := "restsample"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.9",
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache
)


play.Project.playJavaSettings
```

When i run it, i get a

```
info] Updating {file:/Users/mateen.sajjad/play-learn/restsample/}restsample...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[error] Modules were resolved with conflicting cross-version suffixes in {file:/Users/mateen.sajjad/play-learn/restsample/}restsample:
[error]    org.scala-stm:scala-stm _2.10.0, _2.10
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:update for the full output.
[error] (*:update) Conflicting cross-version suffixes in: org.scala-stm:scala-stm
[error] Total time: 6 s, completed Nov 7, 2013 1:41:33 PM
```

so i am stuck ? Can anyone help me please  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is no release of the play reactive mongo plugin that works with play 2.2 yet but 0.10-SNAPSHOT should work.

Here is a discussion about it on the reactive mongo google group: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/reactivemongo/R9TiVINofrk/discussion